# What do you call a fixed point theorem for a mapping from a subset of a space to the whole space?

Tags: ho.history-overview, terminology, fixed-point-theorems

There are a number of fixed point theorems in which we have a map from some subset of a (metric, topological, ...) space to the whole space.  (Usually, there is some condition regarding the behavior of the function on the boundary of the set in question; an example would be the various nonlinear alternatives, see Granas & Dugundji's monograph.)

Is there any *name* such theorems share in common?

Comment: followed links, eventually found your publications; maybe you should type in a few of your favorite results of the type you mean, at least by name. I never know what to say when people ask for names of things, never sure what is the purpose of knowing a name. For early students, i think it may be to search on Google, but...

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that I'm writing a booklet on fixed point theory, and I'm in search for a good section title;).  When writing papers, I never needed a single name to refer to such theorems.

Comment: Makes sense....

Comment: Is the map usually required surjective?

Comment: No.  (I'll try to include some examples of such theorems when I have a bit of spare time, maybe today in the afternoon.)

Answer (score 1):

I used to be (and still am) interested in the lovely topic f.p.p. but don't know any publications which would provide an answer to your question. Thus you have prompted me to come up with respective terminology.

Let me be systematic. First of all we need a name for functions from a set to its superset. Let's call them ***superfunctions***:

> A function $\ f:X\rightarrow Y\ $ is called a superfunction $\ \ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \ X\subseteq Y.\ $ A superfunction $\ f:X\rightarrow Y\ $ is true (resp. proper) $\ \ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \ X\subseteq f(X)\ \ $(resp. $\ X\subset f(X)$).

In practice, once may often use term *superfunction* to mean true (or proper) superfuntions only. One should say so explicitly then.

This is the keyword: superfunction. Now one can formulate all kind of s.f.p.p. (super fixed point property) for the needed classes of superfunctions with respect to the respective applications. Thus there will be a whole family of related notions.

Comment: If $ f:X\rightarrow Y $ then it makes sense to write $ f:X\rightarrow X\cup Y $ as well. In that sense every function is a superfunction.

Comment: Interesting. But I would use your @Bjørn notation (one just above) only on special occasions.

Answer (score 0):

**Ecumenical** fixed point theorems.

Surjective, prophetic, heraldic, clairvoyant, omnipresent, gestalt, symbiotic

Comment: :-) -- very good!

Comment: ..., encompassing, generous, overwhelming, possessive, sybaritic, ... (*in the alphabetic order*).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, all good suggestions. You seem to know this area, are the maps under discussion usually surjective?

Comment: Perhaps, @Will Jagy, someone like Andrzej Granas would know (I am not well read, sorry).

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, alright. That strikes me as a possible name or part of a phrase, a likely feature of many such things, either as a hypothesis or early conclusion on the way to proof.

Comment: Could you, @Will Jagy, be a little more specific? *(How come I can't get @ at the beginning of my comments? Yeah, another discrimination).*

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, I do not actually know what theorems he has in mind; I am just picturing an open disc in $\mathbb R^2,$ continuous mapping, if you can just translate the thing you do not get any fixpoint; surjectivity would rule that out. Meanwhile, surjectivity is not a feature of Brouwer, Lefschetz theorems, where a space is mapped to itself. Oh, I think it disables @ signs when a notification will be automatic.

Comment: Hey, @mbork, are you still around? Karol Sieklucki (summer 1961, private communication) got a very simple fixed point free map of a disk onto a superspace of that disk. I have a fixed point free map of a disc **onto** a larger disk. I don't have offhand any such example which would be nice enough to preserve orientation in a meaningful sense (piecewise linear, piecewise differentiable, ...). Is there any?

Comment: Yes, I'm here.  I'll be in my office in a few hours, and I'll be able to give some examples then.  For starters: one kind of such theorems is a compact mapping from a convex set to the whole (say, Banach) space such that the boundary is sent to the set in question.  (Some assumption may be missing, but you get an idea.)